# Xcode: no such file or directory error

Tags: xcode, macos

So I'm trying to adapt a file maker plugin to work on a Mac with xcode. There is code already written and compiled for the plugin but we need to update because a lot of internal changes have been made. I open the project in xcode and hit build and I'm given something like 135 errors saying that these files don't exist (e.g. "error: FMWrapper/FMXExtern.h: No such file or directory"). The issue is I'm looking at these files right now, they certainly exist, it's just that they aren't getting read. I've moved them through the project to nearly every file and I still get the same error. The lines that are causing the errors are as such:

```
#include "FMWrapper/FMXExtern.h"
```

And so on...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler won't scan your whole hard disk for included files recursively (unless you ask it to -- but don't! :). You need to help it out. Otherwise, your builds would take ages.

One way is to **specify the path to these sources** using the Xcode build setting `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` or `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`.

So you tell Xcode to add the directory that contains `FMWrapper/` to the search paths.

---

[Xcode Build Setting Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)